# pyPandas: default columns names

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas

If read a file with default column names, how do call them after?
`df[1]` seems to work almost all of the time. However, it complains about types when writing conditions like:

```
In [60]: cond = ((df[1] != node) & (df[2] != deco))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/ferreirafm/work/colab/SNP/rawdata/<ipython-input-60-513a433bfeb5> in <module>()
----> 1 cond = ((df[1] != node) & (df[2] != deco))

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in wrapper(self, other)
140             if np.isscalar(res):
141                 raise TypeError('Could not compare %s type with Series'
--> 142                                 % type(other))
143             return Series(na_op(values, other),
144                           index=self.index, name=self.name)

TypeError: Could not compare <type 'str'> type with Series
```

Treat dataframe columns by default names are more appropriate for my applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you compare a series of scalar values to a string:

```
In [73]: node = 'a'

In [74]: deco = 'b'

In [75]: data = [(10, 'a', 1), (11, 'b', 2), (12, 'c', 3)]

In [76]: df = pd.DataFrame(data)

In [77]: df
Out[77]: 
    0  1  2
0  10  a  1
1  11  b  2
2  12  c  3

In [78]: cond = ((df[1] != node) & (df[2] != deco))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-0afad3702859> in <module>()
----> 1 cond = ((df[1] != node) & (df[2] != deco))

/home/.../python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in wrapper(self, other)
    140             if np.isscalar(res):
    141                 raise TypeError('Could not compare %s type with Series'
--> 142                                 % type(other))
    143             return Series(na_op(values, other),
    144                           index=self.index, name=self.name)

TypeError: Could not compare <type 'str'> type with Series
```

Note that pandas can handle strings and numbers in a series, but it not really makes sense to compare strings and numbers, so the error message is useful.
However pandas should perhaps give a more detailed error message.

If your condition for the column 2 would be a number it would work:

```
In [79]: deco = 3

In [80]: cond = ((df[1] != node) & (df[2] != deco))

In [81]: df[cond]
Out[81]: 
    0  1  2
1  11  b  2
```

**Some comments:**

Maybe some of your confusion is due to a design decision in pandas:

If you read data from a file with `read_csv` the default column names of the resulting data frame are set to `X.1` to `X.N` (and to `X1` to `XN` for versions >= 0.9), which are strings.

If you create a data frame from exiting arrays or lists or something the column names default to `0` to `N` and are integers.

```
In [23]: df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), header=None)

In [24]: df.columns
Out[24]: Index([X.1, X.2, X.3], dtype=object)

In [25]: df.columns[0]
Out[25]: 'X.1'

In [26]: type(df.columns[0])
Out[26]: str

In [27]: df = pd.DataFrame(randn(2,3))

In [30]: df.columns
Out[30]: Int64Index([0, 1, 2])

In [31]: df.columns[0]
Out[31]: 0

In [32]: type(df.columns[0])
Out[32]: numpy.int64
```

I opened a [ticket](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2034) to discuss this.

So your

```
In [60]: cond = ((df[1] != node) & (df[2] != deco))
```

should work for a dataframe created from an array or something, if the type of `df[1]` and `df[2]` is the same as the type of `node` and `deco`.

If you have read a file with `read_csv` than

```
In [60]: cond = ((df['X.2'] != node) & (df['X.3'] != deco))
```

should work with versions < 0.9, while it should be

```
In [60]: cond = ((df['X2'] != node) & (df['X3'] != deco))
```

with versions >= 0.9.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I think the big mistake here is the version which I'm using. For Pandas 0.8.1 `df[1]` works when using DataFrame construtor, but not when reading from files. When reading df from files is mandatory to set names (colnames) for read_csv (`df['Name']` - no problems with str comparisons), on the other hand neither `df[1]` nor `df['x.1']` will work. I'm not criticizing, Pandas is great! Wouldn't be more pythonic to use the same default columns name whatever the way you build your DataFrame? Best.

Comment: to use the same default column names is what I suggested in the ticket.

Comment: however I think your original problem should be due to a comparison of a string with a series of numbers. Can you please edit your example and show the values of `node` and `deco`.

Comment: as I said, I couldn't be able to make things work using all of the default column names suggested. The solution was to set columns names when reading csv. Have a look [here](http://bpaste.net/show/50031/).

Comment: the code there is different from the code you posted here. But from the error message it is clear that it was a problem of compariosn with a string. Maybe you can update your question.

Comment: yep, I had to do those changes to make things happen. However, from my experience, if you change the code a bit using the default columns name (anyone suggested), you gonna see the string comparison errors. Anyway... thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

I`m on pandas master, here default column names after reading a file are certainly not 0, 1, 2, .. Note that you can use df.icol() to select a column by position. This way there is no dependency if column names have been set, or default column names are used.

```
In [93]: data = """\
1,2,3
4,5,6
"""

In [94]: df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), header=None)

In [95]: df
Out[95]:
   X0  X1  X2
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6

In [96]: df.icol(0)
Out[96]:
0    1
1    4
Name: X0
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know. Because, it works for `df = DataFrame(randn(2,3)) df[0]`. Wierd!

Comment: ... also, after reading a file, I've got `Name: X.1` when df.icol(0). Bleeding edge?

Comment: The change from X.1 to X1 is recent (https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2000). Default column names when reading from file are different then default column names when using one of the DataFrame constructors.

Comment: Could we use, in future versions, df[X1] then?

Comment: @fred the column names are strings in this case, so it should be df['X1'] or df['X.1'] for versions < 0.9.